# How the BasicObject, Object, and Kernel interact each other?

Tags: ruby

To understand how the `BasicObject, Object, and Kernel` interact each other, I thought about the below code,which is found from the *page#100* of the David A Black's book:

```
class BasicObject
# a scant seven method definitions go here
end
module Kernel
# over 100 method definitions go here!
end
class Object < BasicObject
# one or two private methods go here,
# but the main point is to mix in the Kernel module
include Kernel
end
```

Object is a subclass of BasicObject. Every class that doesn't have an explicit super-
class is a subclass of Object. You can see evidence of this default in irb:

```
class C
end
#=>nil
C.superclass
#=>Object
```

Okay,but the below **BOLD** lines of David Black's in his book made me confused to understand:

"Every class has Object—and therefore Kernel and `BasicObject` —among its ancestors .ofcourse, ***there’s still the paradox that `BasicObject` is an `Object`, and `Object` is a `Class`,and `Class` is an `Object`. But as you saw earlier, a bit of circularity in the class model serves to jump-start the hierarchy; and once set in motion, it operates logically.and cleanly."***

Here are my questions:

1. Why did he mention the relationship as **paradox** of
   `BasicObject` is an `Object`, and `Object` is a `Class`,and `Class`
   is an `Object`?
2. What is the `circularity` ,he here trying to say?

Comment: Could you please give a page reference to the book?

Comment: @N.N. yes, I am reading the pdf version of that book. Its on page#100. If you want I can send that ebook to you also.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I am done.

Comment: Close voter: please let me know what you want me here to do improve? Why it is not a real question and why down-vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing two meanings of "is": "instance of" and "subclass of".

1) Regarding subclass relation:

- `Class` is a subclass of `Module`.
- `Module` is a subclass of `Object`.
- `Object` is a subclass of `BasicObject`.

And due to transitivity, `Class` is a subclass of `Object` and of `BasicObject`, and `Module` is a subclass of `BasicObject`. But there is no circularity here. For example, `BasicObject` is not a subclass of `Class`, `Module`, or `Object`.

2) Regarding instantiation relation:

- `Class` is an instance of `Class` (as well as (kind) of `Module`, `Object`, `BasicObject`).
- `Module` is an instance of `Class` (as well as (kind) of `Module`, `Object`, `BasicObject`).
- `Object` is an instance of `Class` (as well as (kind) of `Module`, `Object`, `BasicObject`).
- `BasicObject` is an instance of `Class` (as well as (kind) of `Module`, `Object`, `BasicObject`).

But there is no circularity in instantiation relation. Circularity is a notion defined on transitive relations. For example, If `A → B` and `B → C`, then it follows that `A → C` due to transitivity, and if it is `C → A` as well, then there is circularity. But instantiation relation is not transitive. "A is an instance of B" and "B is an instance of C" does not mean that "A is an instance of C". So circularity cannot be defined on instantiation relation in a non-trivial way.

Comment: I got down-vote. So I want to improve it if anything I missed there. Could you advice me as last time you did. I don't know who did,but still want to improve it,if I can.

Comment: But I think your question is not actually a question. You are stating things but are not asking anything (except for in the title). That is one problem with it that I can think of.

Comment: Actually that bold part made me too confused,that couldn't understand how to ask the specific to it. Now being a too expert on this language you really caught my real pain, and answered it. I am now reading your answer.

Comment: my bad, I couldn't understand the `instantiation relation` still at fully. I might not say to you,but still asking can those `instantiation relation` be explained with examples? please forgive me if it seems to you I am asking much more.

Comment: Don't ask me. I think it got better.